# ‘EVP_MD_CTX_new’ was not declared in this scope in openssl

Tags: openssl, sha

I am using the template from OpenSSL documentation and gets the following error. Trying the alternate of using init is also not working. I'm using openssl version 1.1.1(checked by command `openssl version`)

> error: ‘EVP_MD_CTX_new’ was not declared in this scope error
>
> note: suggested alternative: ‘EVP_MD_CTX_init’
>
> ‘EVP_MD_CTX_free’ was not declared in this scope

```
void digest_message(const unsigned char *message, size_t message_len, unsigned char **digest, unsigned int *digest_len)
{
    EVP_MD_CTX *mdctx;

    if((mdctx = EVP_MD_CTX_create()) == NULL)
        printf("error while hahsing");
//      handleErrors();

    if(1 != EVP_DigestInit_ex(mdctx, EVP_sha256(), NULL))
        printf("error while hahsing");

    if(1 != EVP_DigestUpdate(mdctx, message, message_len))
        printf("error while hahsing");

    if((*digest = (unsigned char *)OPENSSL_malloc(EVP_MD_size(EVP_sha256()))) == NULL)
        printf("error while hahsing");

    if(1 != EVP_DigestFinal_ex(mdctx, *digest, digest_len))
        printf("error while hahsing");

    EVP_MD_CTX_destroy(mdctx);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The [openssl API changed](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.0/man3/EVP_MD_CTX_free.html) with version 1.1:

> `EVP_MD_CTX_create()` and `EVP_MD_CTX_destroy()` were renamed to `EVP_MD_CTX_new()` and `EVP_MD_CTX_free()` in OpenSSL 1.1.